# Karma: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am new to Angular World and very beginner at Karma.
I am receiving the following error when I am trying to run the Karma-Jasmine Unit test.

```
{
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/nomod?p0=app", "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.\nhttp://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.9/$injector/nomod?p0=app"
}
```

Going through various posts, I found that this error occurs when:

1. Misspelled the module name
2. Forget to register the module
3. Forget to load dependencies

But it seems that none of the above issue applies to my app. My App is very small as of now. I am posting my almost whole app for reference.
Please find my code below for reference.

**app.module.js**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

    angular
        .module("app", [
            "ngRoute",
            "ngMessages",
            "ngclipboard",
            "ui.router"
        ])
        .config(configurations);


    function configurations($locationProvider, $routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

        $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");

        $routeProvider
            .when("/licensing", {
                templateUrl: "app/licensing/licensing.html",
                controller: "LicensingController",
                controllerAs: "vm"
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: "/licensing"
            });

    }
})();
```

**index.html**

```
<!-- Angular Libraries -->
<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="./scripts/clipboard.js"></script>
<script src="./libs/angular/angular-clipboard.js"></script>
<script src="./app/app.module.js"></script>

<!-- Controllers -->
<script src="./app/authentication/login.controller.js"></script>
<script src="./app/authentication/forgetpassword.controller.js"></script>
<script src="./app/licensing/licensing.controller.js"></script>
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  './node_modules/angular/angular.js', // Angular Framework
  './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.js', // UI-Router
  './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', // Loads the Module for Tests
  './app/licensing/licensing.controller.js', // Licensing Controller
  './app/app.module.js', // Our Angular App
  './app/licensing/licensing.controller.spec.js' // Licensing Controller Spec File
],
```

**license.controller.js**

```
(function () {
"use strict";

    angular
        .module("app")
        .controller("LicensingController", LicensingController)

    function LicensingController() {
        // Some code
    }

 })();
```

**licensing.controller.spec.js**

```
describe("Licensing Form", function () {

    var LicensingController;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("app"));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_LicensingController_) {
        LicensingController = _LicensingController_;
    }));

    it("This is a Dummy Test for (2 + 2)", function () {
        expect(2 + 2).toEqual(4);
    });
});
```

Comment: I updated the module name of license.controller from "app" to "app.license". Then in specs, updated to "app.license" from "app" and everything is working fine. Don't know what is problem with "app" module, but updating the module name works. It's weird but still it works. I don't understand a thing behind it. Sorry.

Comment: Hi Ankit, did you find a solution? I have similar issue

Comment: @BeckiD:- In my above comment, I have mentioned what I did in my Solution. But one thing I know for sure, that this error happens when you have declared the Module, but either not injected the Module properly or not referenced the Module properly.